# In Python, What is the process and importance of 'a' > 'A' being True?

Tags: python

I've tried various search terms in Google and I have tried to find an answer from the official docs but I cannot find a reasonable (read: understandable) explanation why this is the case in Python.

I understand that it's something to do with lexicographical order.

The expression 'a' > 'A' is regarded as **True**

But why is this the case? Or rather, why does this need to be the case?

Sorry if this is phrased badly, this is my first ever question on this site.

Comment: http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should make the ordering clearer:

```
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> ord('A')
65
>>> ord('a') > ord('A')
True
```

The character code for `'a'` is greater than the one for `'A'`.

Answer (score 1):

### `ord('a')` returns an integer representing the Unicode code. The `ord()` is the inverse of `chr()`.

The Unicode standard describes how characters are represented by code points. A code point is an integer value, usually denoted in base 16. In the standard, a code point is written using the notation U+12CA to mean the character with value 0x12ca (4,810 decimal). The Unicode standard contains a lot of tables listing characters and their corresponding code points:

```
0061    'a'; LATIN SMALL LETTER A
0062    'b'; LATIN SMALL LETTER B
0063    'c'; LATIN SMALL LETTER C
...
007B    '{'; LEFT CURLY BRACKET
```

Read more here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html